# How do I stop the infinite loop of CellPainting Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I need to draw image button of Datagridview by this code

```
    Private Sub CtrlDataGridView2_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles CtrlDataGridView2.CellPainting
            Try
                If e.RowIndex >= 0 And e.Handled = False Then
                    If CtrlDataGridView2.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name ="ADD" Then
                       Dim bmpImage As Bitmap                    
                       bmpImage = My.Resources.Add                     
                       e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
                       e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpImage, CInt((e.CellBounds.Width / 2) - (bmpImage.Width / 2)) + e.CellBounds.X, CInt((e.CellBounds.Height / 2) - (bmpImage.Height / 2)) + e.CellBounds.Y)
                       e.Handled = True
                     End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                LogException(ex)
            End Try
```

But it has a problem because it's access to this event every time.

Comment: This event will fire a *lot* of times.  Once for every visible cell in the DGV.  And when you debug and switch back-and-forth between your program and VS then that will start all over again.  It does have a bug, you have to use the Using statement on *bmpImage* to ensure it gets disposed.  Without it your program will very rapidly run out of memory, the garbage collector is unlikely to run often enough given how often the event fires.  Really rather best to access My.Resources.Add just once in your constructor so you don't create that bitmap over and over again.

Comment: What Hans said is correct, but you are also causing the cells to repaint from within the cellpainting event...so unless you put all that code inside of some sort of If or use a different event to trigger painting, each paint will register with the listener which will paint again which will register again which will paint again which ...well, u get the picture...